# Convert this java array to a kotlin equivalent array 2d

Tags: java, android, arrays, kotlin

Hi I'm trying to convert this java array to a kotlin array:

```
String[][] data = {{"May","22"},
                        {"June","45"}};
```

I tried two ways but my tableView is not showing any record.
This is my way number 1:

```
val mayo: Array<String> = arrayOf("Mayo", "20")
val junio: Array<String> = arrayOf("Junio", "40")
val data2d1 = arrayOf(mayo, junio)
```

The I pased this array to the adapter of this library:
https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView

```
  tableViewSalesPerMonth.dataAdapter = SimpleTableDataAdapter(requireContext(), data2d1)
```

[image]

and nothing happens, there is not data and not errors.

And this the way number 2 I created the next array by using the first array `data2d1`:

```
    val data2d2 = mutableListOf<Array<String>>()
    data2d2.addAll(data2d1)
```

This arrays that I did are wrong? I need something like:

```
  String[][] data = {{"May","22"},
                            {"June","45"}};
```

but in kotlin code.
Please guys if you have any idea to fix this problem I will appreciate it.
Thanks so much.

Comment: `var values = arrayOf(arrayOf("may", "33"), arrayOf("jun","32"))` may be ok but my table doesn't show anything.

Comment: This looks correct.  Can you elaborate on what goes wrong?

Comment: The problem seem to be the libray is not showing any record.

Comment: Are you quite certain you didn't make any typos?  There is no possible difference between your code and the Java code you have shown us.

Comment: No errors bro. I will implement the default tableLayout of android instead of this library

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is nested array, your second approach was correct.

```kotlin
val arr: Array<Array<String>> = arrayOf(
    arrayOf("May","222"),
    arrayOf("Hell","222")
)
```